# Matlab code for converting collection of tiffs to avi isn't working

Tags: matlab, loops, tiff, avi

I want to convert 95 tiffs to an avi.

this is the code I'm using:

```
 v = VideoWriter('newfile.avi','Uncompressed AVI');
 open(v);
 %95 images
 for k=1:95      
     yr=2005;
     icnt=yr+1;
frame = sprintf('scale%dRCP2.6.tif', icnt);
     input = imread(frame);

     writeVideo(v,input);
 end
 close(v);
```

It creates the avi file, but it only seems to pull in one image?
I think it's probably a problem with when the frame is being read in within the loop but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

I have also tried this approach:

```
    % Create a video writer object
writerObj = VideoWriter('Video.avi');

% Set frame rate
writerObj.FrameRate = 10;

% Open video writer object and write frames sequentially
open(writerObj)
yr=2005;
for i=1:95;
icnt=yr+1;
frame = sprintf('scale%dRCP2.6.tif', icnt);
     input = imread(frame);

     % Write frame now
     writeVideo(writerObj, input);
end

% Close the video writer object
close(writerObj);
```

But the avi does not work at all using this code. There are no images being pulled in to it.

Comment: Please consider changing the title of your question, as this is not a problem related to tiff sequence conversion to avi. This is just "_Why my code converting image sequence to avi video is not working as expected?_"

Comment: In future, try debugging - for example by printing out the file names before you read them or viewing each image loaded before adding them to the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the source image format (tiff), you are just adding always the same image `scale2006RCP2.6.tif`.

Taking into account the first code, the mistake is `icnt=yr+1`, which I guess it should be `icnt=yr+i` instead;

Fixed that, it worked correctly on my Matlab2016b with ten images on my Windows pc. Some remarks:

- specify the framerate (as you did in your second code), but consider that watching 10 figures per second is too much: `v.FrameRate = 1` sounds better;
- verify all the images have the same size. If not, consider rescaling all of them to the same size.